# Suddenly my Parse app stopped reading some Css file

Tags: html, css, parse-platform, mime-types, parse-framework

Suddenly my parse website stopped reading specific css files , without me doing any changes or deployments.

and when i navigate to the browsers (firefox v 43.0.2) console i get the error:

The stylesheet http://......regstyles.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "application/x-css", is not "text/css" .

I have tried also chrome (Version 47.0.2526.106 m) and explorer (Version : 9.0.9) and still my css files are not read.

Can some one guide where exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to this message:

> The stylesheet http://......regstyles.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "application/x-css", is not "text/css"

the problem is that browser expect CSS file to have MIME type "text/css".

More over, in [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files) you can find that:

> The W3C specification mentions that CSS files should be served with a "text/css" MIME type.

So, it seems like setting correct MIME type for CSS you try to link will solve your problem.